# Highcharts / HighStock issue, series disappearing on dynamic update

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this high stocks area chart, consuming a JSON api.  Each n seconds, the chart recalls the API for the delta in points.

After a few minutes, the left hand side series disappears, however, if you mouse over it, the labels still appear. Happens on Mac and Windows, FF IE Chrome and Safari.  Would appreciate any help.

You can view a demo here:

https://dev-mv-charts.azurewebsites.net/goldarea.htm

Update:  If I use the below code, take from the highcharts site, it seems to work.  Just need to replace the initial load of random data now.

```
$(function () {

Highcharts.setOptions({
    global : {
        useUTC : true
    }
});

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart : {
        events : {
            load : function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {

                    var _update_url = 'http://api.bullionmark.com/v1/ask?currencyId=2&commodityId=1';

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: _update_url}).done(function (resp1) {

                            var x2 = parseInt(resp1.Timestamp) * 1000;
                            var y2 = parseFloat(resp1.Current);

                            //var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            //y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

                            series.addPoint([x2, y2], true, true);

                        });

                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title : {
        text : 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series : [{
        name : 'Random data',
        type : 'area',
        data : (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

            for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});

});
```

Comment: Your demo shows black screen only..

Comment: Try on http not https.  Working for me, albeit after about 10seconds.  The backend API is slow.

Comment: Works fine for me.. how long do I have to wait? Anyway, update Highstock to 2.1.7.

Comment: ll update tomorrow. I had it running inspecting with fiddler, and couldn't see any nulls or anything. Seems to break about after 4 ticks, so 20 or 25mins.

Comment: Any chance to change "5*60*1000" to for example 1minute? Also, try to remove gradient - maybe something is wrong with parsing that colors.

Comment: I've uddated high stocks js. Its also ticking every minute, and I've removed the gradient, still no luck.  I performance tuned the API too so its loading a lot quicker.   Still same issue.  Looking at the requests in fiddler show all the JSON is correct, no nulls being returned by the API.

Comment: What I have noticed, is it seems to break on the second update.

Comment: Did you test with chart.redraw();?

Comment: It's caused by gapSize. Remove that option, otherwise you will have huge gap: initial gap between points is one hour, but later you add points every 5minutes. Then gap size = 5 means 25minutes distance between points acceptable, otherwise it will split points. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/14jL9no0/25/ (comment out option gapSize and it will work fine).